# insert data into multiple table through postman

Tags: node.js, postman

I have two tables
1) Department 
2) Emp

how can i insert data into both data from one API though postman.

### Department

{
"dept_no":1,
"dept_name":"HeadOffice"
"dept_loc":"Location1"
}

### Employee

{
"emp_no":10001,
"ename":"ABC",
"dept_no":1
}

Thanks

Comment: Postman is used for making HTTP requests. It has nothing to do with inserting data into tables. You have to create your own backend, your own api then you can perform api calls from postman.

Comment: API is already developed. But now problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

{

"Dept":[
{
"dept_no":"Warehouse18",
"dept_loc":"Karachi-west"
}
],
"Emp":[
{
"deptid":10,
"empno":"20",
"ename":"Owais1",
"job":"Senior Accountant",
"sal":50000
},
{
"deptid":20,
"empno":"30",
"ename":"Farhan1",
"job":"Manager",
"sal":50000
}

```
]
```

}